# How to check if a user is logged in?

Tags: login, command-line, php

how do i check from within a php script, if a user is logged in? My current way is, to get the output of

```
w | grep <username>
```

and check, if there is output. It works, if a user is logged in via gdm, kdm or ssh or login on a tty. But what it doesn't get is, if an other user opened a terminal and run `su <username>`, this shell process is not reported, how do i get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if userA uses `su` to become userB, then userB is still not logged in.

However, how about this:

```
ps -u <username>
```

Then you can check `$? -eq 0` to see if any processes were found belonging to that user. However, if there are any long-running processes owned by that user, then it will still show them. If that's no good, you could check for their shell.